# crontab taks not running

Tags: bash, nginx

signed in as root user, `crontab -e`  has a single line entry:

```
*/1 * * * * /opt/launch-crashed-services.sh > /dev/null 2>
```

the `/opt` directory has the following permissions defined for that script

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root             root  179 Sep 20 06:47 launch-crashed-services.sh
```

which should thus run every minute a check that nginx is running and restart if not, dumping the output to a log file.

```
service nginx status | grep 'active (running)' > /dev/null 2>&1

if [ $? != 0 ]
then
        sudo service nginx restart > /var/log/nginx/relaunch.log  # /dev/null
fi
```

The status of nginx is frequently inactive for long periods & said log file is empty.
Thus this script is either not being fired or somehow fires, but incorrectly.

Where is this set-up mistaken?

Comment: `2>` is not a valid redirect. Also, when troubleshooting something like this, you should *not* be sending output and errors to /dev/null; send them somewhere where you can look at them, and see what they indicate about what's happening as it runs. BTW, using `sudo` when the job's already running as root is pointless.

Comment: What would be a valid redirect ?  Specifically, one for troubleshooting, then another when matters are apaprently normal?     & yes,  I did set-up for the restart a specific log.

Comment: Use `>/dev/null 2>&1`.

Comment: For troubleshooting, use something like `>> /tmp/cronjob.log 2>&1` (and remove the redirect on the `service ... | grep ...` command inside the script). When it's working properly, you can discard output & errors with `>/dev/null 2>&1` (note that the `&1` part is missing in what you have now).

Comment: It may be worthwhile to take a step back and find a solution that meets the requirements better. First, there is no reason to monitor and restart `nginx` using ill-designed and outdated tools like `cron`; `systemd` is way better at supervising and/or restarting of services. Second, `cron` is better avoided, because [`systemd` timers](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) are [_way better_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73769882/relaunching-a-crontab-automatically-unix#comment130274833_73769882). In particular, logging and log storage works out-of-the-box.